# Add where clauses to sql select dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a webshop admin, i am listing out the orders from sql. Here, i have a search form also, where i type in a keyword, and start search.

Now, i added a date from, and a date end input to the form. How can i add these to the sql select, if the admin enter the dates, not just the keyword only?

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="text" name="date_from" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date_from'])) { echo $_POST['date_from'];} ?>" size="7"  class="datepicker">
    <span> - </span>
    <input type="text" name="date_end" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date_end'])) { echo $_POST['date_end'];} ?>" size="7"  class="datepicker">
</td> 

$sql = "SELECT rendeles_user_id , rendeles_id, nev, status, vegosszeg,br_vegosszeg, datum, ido, egyeb FROM rendeles_adatok WHERE $kereses_helye LIKE '%$kw%' ORDER BY $kereses_rendezes $kereses_sorrend";
```

`$kereses_helye` means that where i want to search. (user name, order id, email....)

Comment: where are you assigning $kereses_helye?  Show the complete code or this is not something that can really be helped.  Make sure you have the form sending and receiving the data.  This is too hard to follow right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the `where` clause before the sql statement based upon the existence of POST date values - it's not pretty and this and the original code are vulnerable to sql injection. I assumed ( probably incorrectly ) in the query that the column `datum` was a date column in the db

```
$where = !empty( $_POST['date_from'] ) && !empty( $_POST['date_end'] ) ? "where `$kereses_helye` like '%$kw%' and `datum` between '{$_POST['date_from']}' and '{$_POST['date_end']}' " : "where `$kereses_helye` like '%$kw%'";

$sql = "select 
    rendeles_user_id,
    rendeles_id,
    nev,
    status,
    vegosszeg,
    br_vegosszeg,
    datum,
    ido,
    egyeb 
    from rendeles_adatok 
    {$where}
    order by $kereses_rendezes $kereses_sorrend";
```

Comment: But if date_from is empty, and date_end is not empty?

Comment: `!empty( $_POST['date_from'] ) && !empty( $_POST['date_end'] )` ~ it should require both be NOT empty to proceed